# How to Make an adjacency list from CSV file having 2 columns source and target respectively

Tags: python, adjacency-list

I need to make an adjacency list from a CSV file which has two columns source and target respectively in python language. but I am clueless as of now as to how to do it. I am attaching the file as how csv looks.
[The csv looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMunI.png)

Comment: Please can you add to your question what the expected output is? And what you already have tried?

Comment: @3DspatialUser I just need a adjacency list showing 0 if there is no link, or 1 if there is a link.

Comment: @3DspatialUser I tried using nested dictionaries but couldn't go further after that.

Comment: Please edit your answer with what you tried. And it is not clear (at least to me) when there is a link. I see a column with identical values and a column with two words in it (names?) At the top I suppose that there are column names (target and source)? But it is all left for interpretation instead of asking a clear question with this is what I have, this is what I want and this is what I tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.